# Palindrome with numbers in between

Tags: java, palindrome

I was trying to write some sample codes for testing Palindrome text in java.

I did some testing.

For eaxmple:

1STA22TS1 is Palindrome or not?

If you guys say yes, then i would like to post my code. Coz i am .equals as false.

Comment: No it is not ! Please see what palindrome means :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome

Comment: If you have a doubt/problem, directly ask that... If your understanding is wrong, people will correct you...

Comment: Although StackOverflow isn't necessarily the place for a discussion on what makes a palindrome...

Comment: @tim_yates the question asked for it directly if the given string is a palindrome or not.

Comment: And that's programming because...?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the definition of a Palindrome, and not about computer programming.

Comment: OP created tests, and the test returns false. He was unsure if that was correct, and if it wasn't - he was going to ask for programming help. That he created tests without knowing what the answer *should* be is kind of silly - his entire implementation might have been completely invalid and a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Although at the moment this question has nothing to do with programming I'll answer it. No, that is not a palindrome.

Next time do a quick google search first.

> A palindrome is a word, phrase, number, or other sequence of characters which reads the same backward or forward. Allowances may be made for adjustments to capital letters, punctuation, and word dividers. Famous examples include "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!", "Amor, Roma", "race car", "taco cat", "Was it a car or a cat I saw?" and "No 'x' in Nixon".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome